Angular default provider in Module
I have the following example. The idea is to have a default implementation for ActionsServiceBase eg. ActionServiceDefault when any implementation of the abstract class is not provided. For some reason, it doesn't work. Is it technically possible to provide a fallback provider like in the example? I added ActionServiceCustom to the providers array with useExisting as a double check - I am aware it shouldn't be necessary if providedIn: "root" is present in class definition. I know I can workaround it using forRoot() pattern but I intentionally don't want to go this way since we consider migration from modules to standalone in the future.
@Injectable()
export abstract class ActionsServiceBase {
  abstract isRenewing(): boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class ActionServiceDefault extends ActionsServiceBase {
  isRenewing() {
    console.log('ActionServiceDefault');
    return true;
  }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ActionServiceCustom extends ActionsServiceBase {
  isRenewing() {
    console.log('ActionServiceCustom');
    return true;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ActionsServiceBase,
      useFactory: (injector: Injector) => {
        try {
          return injector.get(ActionsServiceBase);
        } catch {
          // Return the default implementation if not found
          console.error('no impl found');
          return new ActionServiceDefault();
        }
      },
      deps: [INJECTOR],
    },
  ],
})
export class CustomModule {}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ActionsServiceBase,
      useExisting: ActionServiceCustom,
    },
    importProvidersFrom(CustomModule),
  ],
});


You are wrapping the injector get, in a try catch block, which is giving you a circular dependency error on ActionsServiceBase.
This is getting hidden by the try catch block, so remove the try catch block.
I suggest you have a override token, which can be used to override the default implementation, here it is ActionsServiceOverride.
const ActionsServiceOverride = new InjectionToken<string>('ActionsServiceOverride');

This get's rid of the circular dependency and you can freely add the override using it's own unique token.
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ActionsServiceBase,
      useFactory: (injector: Injector) => {
          return injector.get(ActionsServiceOverride, null, {
            optional: true,
          }) || new ActionServiceDefault();
      },
      deps: [Injector],
    },
  ],
})
export class CustomModule {}

Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  Injectable,
  NgModule,
  Injector,
  importProvidersFrom,
  inject,
  forwardRef,
  InjectionToken,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  actionsServiceBase = inject(ActionsServiceBase);
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit');
    this.actionsServiceBase.isRenewing();
  }
}
@Injectable()
export abstract class ActionsServiceBase {
  abstract isRenewing(): boolean;
}

const ActionsServiceOverride = new InjectionToken<string>('ActionsServiceOverride');

@Injectable()
export class ActionServiceDefault extends ActionsServiceBase {
  isRenewing() {
    console.log('ActionServiceDefault');
    return true;
  }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ActionServiceCustom extends ActionsServiceBase {
  isRenewing() {
    console.log('ActionServiceCustom');
    return true;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ActionsServiceBase,
      useFactory: (injector: Injector) => {
          return injector.get(ActionsServiceOverride, null, {
            optional: true,
          }) || new ActionServiceDefault();
      },
      deps: [Injector],
    },
  ],
})
export class CustomModule {}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ActionsServiceOverride,
      useExisting: ActionServiceCustom,
    },
    importProvidersFrom(CustomModule),
  ],
});

Stackblitz Demo

I don't think it's a solution. In console received ActionServiceDefault but expected ActionServiceCustom. Additionally you should receive "no impl found" error. Verify it once again. Another idea to workaround it is to change the order of providers so the"custom" provider is latter than the default like it overrides it but I wanted to avoid relying on it.

@PawełOstromecki THe order of the providers matters, so the simplest solution is to change the order, if order is a problem, then please check my updated answer!
